# meeting support in outlook web add-in for mobile

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I need to develop an outlook add-in for mobile (using React) to create and join meetings with an online meeting provider. Should the meeting provider integration be approved by Microsoft by contract? Should this integration have specific requirements?
Moreover it seems I can use the 'MobileOnlineMeetingCommandSurface' extension point to show a mobile button to activate the meeting functionality. Is it possible to manage the button interaction for ouath2 authentication and provide an user rooms list before meeting creation?

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the addin to the Appsource store, there will be a partner agreement. However no separate agreement needs to be signed.
To provide a user room list you could show that as part of the user interaction in the taskpane when user launches on your addin.